# windows virtualenv using global packages

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, django-nonrel

I have the latest versions of virtualenv,django-nonrel, djangotoolbox and django_mongodb_engine. The virtualenv was created with  -no-site-packages.

I attempted to follow the [quick start](http://django-mongodb-engine.github.com/mongodb-engine/) but I see the following errors when trying to run syncdb

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\www\environments\mongotest\djangomongo\manage.py", line 11, in <
module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django-1.2.3-py2.5.egg\django\core\managem
ent\__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django-1.2.3-py2.5.egg\django\core\managem
ent\__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django-1.2.3-py2.5.egg\django\core\managem
ent\__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django-1.2.3-py2.5.egg\django\core\managem
ent\__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django-1.2.3-py2.5.egg\django\utils\import
lib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django-1.2.3-py2.5.egg\django\core\managem
ent\commands\syncdb.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_
signal
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django-1.2.3-py2.5.egg\django\core\managem
ent\sql.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django-1.2.3-py2.5.egg\django\contrib\cont
enttypes\generic.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db import connection
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django-1.2.3-py2.5.egg\django\db\__init__.
py", line 77, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django-1.2.3-py2.5.egg\django\db\utils.py"
, line 91, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django-1.2.3-py2.5.egg\django\db\utils.py"
, line 49, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django_mongodb_engine' isn't an av
ailable database backend.
Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
    'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named django_mongodb_engine.base
```

It appears to be trying to use the default django installation instead of my environments django-nonrel installation.

I have tried adding set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\path\to\env\Lib\site-packages\django but no change.

Any ideas why the default django installation is being used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the file associations under windows. I was trying to syncdb via "manage.py syncdb" which used the default windows python installation. Using "python manage.py syncdb" used the correct python and environment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running `activate.bat`?

Also, I think that setting PYTHONPATH should work, but you'd have to insert new path at the beggining, and it should be path to directory containing django instalation, not to django itself:

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\path\to\env\Lib\site-packages\;%PYTHONPATH%
```

Answer (score 0):

here are my 2 cents to this problem:

using PyDev as eclipse plugin, just pointing to new interpreter to be used with new project solves this issue.